# How to hide a control when it has an invalid binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to hide a control such as a TextBox when it has a binding on a property such as the Text property that is invalid (has thrown a BindingExpression path error). This is different from simply checking to see if the binding's value is null in a trigger. Null may in fact be a perfectly acceptable value, and the control should still be displayed. Basically I have a DataTemplate that I want to reuse with several different types of objects from my VM, some of which may have certain properties in common, and some of them may have unique properties. When a particular property does not exist on the object that is currently the binding source of the DataTemplate, the DataTemplate will have some sort of additional trigger or binding that will hide the particular control that is bound to the property that does not exist.

Comment: I just answered effectively the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893825/mvvm-hiding-a-control-when-bound-property-is-not-present

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with the [Validation.ErrorTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate.aspx) to style the control when a validation error occurs.

Then just set the `ValidatesOnDataError = True` in the binding and away you go

Comment: But what if there is another legitimate validation error? For instance a TextBox.Text bound to an integer and the user types a letter, throwing a validation error (can't parse the integer), then the TextBox disappears.

Comment: Also, setting ValidatesOnDataError = True for the binding, doesn't seem to actually catch the BindingExpression path error

Comment: Hmm yea I obviously didn't think about it. Phil's comment seems like a good solution. FallBackValue and a visibility converter. That would totally work.