# Bind to property only if it exists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF window that uses multiple viewmodel objects as its DataContext.  The window has a control that binds to a property that exists only in some of the viewmodel objects.  How can I bind to the property if it exists (and only if it exists).

I am aware of the following question/answer: [MVVM - hiding a control when bound property is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893825/mvvm-hiding-a-control-when-bound-property-is-not-present). This works, but gives me a warning.  Can it be done without the warning?

Thanks!

Some example code:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="ListView" Margin="25,0,25,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lst}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="Lst_SelectionChanged">
    </ListBox>
    <local:SubControl Grid.Row="3" x:Name="subControl" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedVM}"/>
</Grid>
```

SubControl Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.SubControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation ="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5">
        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=OnOffAlways}"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Always}">
            <TextBlock Text="On/Off"/>
        </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation ="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5">
        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=OnOffSometimes}"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Sometimes}">
            <TextBlock Text="On/Off"/>
        </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow Code Behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel1 vm1;
    ViewModel2 vm2;
    MainViewModel mvm;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        vm1 = new ViewModel1();
        vm2 = new ViewModel2();
        mvm = new MainViewModel();
        mvm.SelectedVM = vm1;
        DataContext = mvm;
    }

    private void Lst_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lstBx = sender as ListBox;

        if (lstBx != null)
        {
            if (lstBx.SelectedItem.Equals("VM 1"))
                mvm.SelectedVM = vm1;
            else if (lstBx.SelectedItem.Equals("VM 2"))
                mvm.SelectedVM = vm2;
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel (DataContext of MainWindow):

```
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<string> lst;
    ViewModelBase selectedVM;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainViewModel()
    {

        Lst = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Lst.Add("VM 1");
        Lst.Add("VM 2");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Lst
    {
        get { return lst; }
        set
        {
            lst = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Lst");
        }
    }


    public ViewModelBase SelectedVM
    {
        get { return selectedVM; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedVM != value)
            {
                selectedVM = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedVM");
            }
        }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel1 (with sometimes property):

```
    public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _always;
    private string _onOffAlways;

    private bool _sometimes;
    private string _onOffSometimes;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModel1()
    {
        _always = false;
        _onOffAlways = "Always Off";

        _sometimes = false;
        _onOffSometimes = "Sometimes Off";
    }

    public bool Always
    {
        get { return _always; }
        set
        {
            _always = value;
            if (_always)
                OnOffAlways = "Always On";
            else
                OnOffAlways = "Always Off";
            OnPropertyChanged("Always");
        }
    }

    public string OnOffAlways
    {
        get { return _onOffAlways; }
        set
        {
            _onOffAlways = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OnOffAlways");
        }
    }

    public bool Sometimes
    {
        get { return _sometimes; }
        set
        {
            _sometimes = value;
            if (_sometimes)
                OnOffSometimes = "Sometimes On";
            else
                OnOffSometimes = "Sometimes Off";
            OnPropertyChanged("Sometimes");
        }
    }

    public string OnOffSometimes
    {
        get { return _onOffSometimes; }
        set
        {
            _onOffSometimes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OnOffSometimes");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel2 (without Sometimes property):

```
    public class ViewModel2 : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _always;
    private string _onOffAlways;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModel2()
    {
        _always = false;
        _onOffAlways = "Always Off";
    }

    public bool Always
    {
        get { return _always; }
        set
        {
            _always = value;
            if (_always)
                OnOffAlways = "Always On";
            else
                OnOffAlways = "Always Off";
            OnPropertyChanged("Always");
        }
    }

    public string OnOffAlways
    {
        get { return _onOffAlways; }
        set
        {
            _onOffAlways = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OnOffAlways");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}

public class AlwaysVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IValueConverter

    public object Convert(object value,
                          Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: _" The window has a control that binds to a property that exists only in some of the viewmodel objects"_ -- why? Why not match your data templates to objects so that the template in use only binds to properties known to exist? And it's not clear from your question or code what it is you expect to actually happen. If you can do it, albeit with a warning, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I'm trying to add this control to an existing usercontrol that is used within the window.  I could create a new version of this usercontrol but it would mean duplicating some code.  I created the example code to show the issue I am seeing.  I would like to be able to bind to the Sometimes property when it exists and not get an error or warning when it does not exist.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: _"Is there a way to do that?"_ -- sure, but not using the architecture you've chosen. _Some_ kind of change will be required. And without you explaining why you're not doing things the usual way, without you explaining why the warning is a problem, and without you explaining what _precisely_ you want to happen when the property doesn't exist, it's not possible to know what answer you need or want.

Comment: More specifically: the code you posted will _never_ have the property in question. So the obvious trivial answer is to just delete the XAML that tries to bind to the never-existing property. You need to provide a better [mcve] that shows clearly what the _real_ scenario looks like and why you can't accommodate the property difference through proper use of templating.

Comment: Thanks for your work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many different ways one could approach your scenario. For what it's worth, the solution you already have seems reasonable to me. The warning you get (I presume you are talking about the error message output to the debug console) is reasonably harmless. It does imply a potential performance issue, as it indicates WPF is recovering from an unexpected condition. But I would expect the cost to be incurred only when the view model changes, which should not be frequent enough to matter.

Another option, which is IMHO the preferred one, is to just use the usual WPF data templating features. That is, define a different template for each view model you expect, and then let WPF pick the right one according to the current view model. That would look something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSO46736914MissingProperty.UserControl1"
             x:ClassModifier="internal"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO46736914MissingProperty"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Content="{Binding}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ViewModel1}">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation ="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5">
          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=OnOffAlways}"/>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Always}">
            <TextBlock Text="On/Off"/>
          </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation ="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5">
          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=OnOffSometimes}"/>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Sometimes}">
            <TextBlock Text="On/Off"/>
          </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ViewModel2}">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation ="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5">
          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=OnOffAlways}"/>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Always}">
            <TextBlock Text="On/Off"/>
          </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

I.e. just set the `Content` of your `UserControl` object to the view model object itself, so that the appropriate template is used to display the data in the control. The template for the view model object that doesn't have the property, doesn't reference that property and so no warning is generated.

Yet another option, which like the above also addresses your concern about the displayed warning, is to create a "shim" (a.k.a. "adapter") object that mediates between the unknown view model type and a consistent one the `UserControl` can use. For example:

```
class ViewModelWrapper : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private readonly dynamic _viewModel;

    public ViewModelWrapper(object viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        HasSometimes = viewModel.GetType().GetProperty("Sometimes") != null;
        _viewModel.PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)_OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void _OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _RaisePropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }

    public bool Always
    {
        get { return _viewModel.Always; }
        set { _viewModel.Always = value; }
    }

    public string OnOffAlways
    {
        get { return _viewModel.OnOffAlways; }
        set { _viewModel.OnOffAlways = value; }
    }

    public bool Sometimes
    {
        get { return HasSometimes ? _viewModel.Sometimes : false; }
        set { if (HasSometimes) _viewModel.Sometimes = value; }
    }

    public string OnOffSometimes
    {
        get { return HasSometimes ? _viewModel.OnOffSometimes : null; }
        set { if (HasSometimes) _viewModel.OnOffSometimes = value; }
    }

    private bool _hasSometimes;
    public bool HasSometimes
    {
        get { return _hasSometimes; }
        private set { _UpdateField(ref _hasSometimes, value); }
    }
}
```

This object uses the `dynamic` feature in C# to access the known property values, and uses reflection on construction to determine whether or not it should try to access the `Sometimes` (and related `OnOffSometimes`) property (accessing the property via the `dynamic`-typed variable when it doesn't exist would throw an exception).

It also implements the `HasSometimes` property so that the view can dynamically adjust itself accordingly. Finally, it also proxies the underlying `PropertyChanged` event, to go along with the delegated properties themselves.

To use this, a little bit of code-behind for the `UserControl` is needed:

```
partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModelWrapper ViewModelWrapper { get; private set; }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        DataContextChanged += _OnDataContextChanged;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void _OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModelWrapper = new ViewModelWrapper(DataContext);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ViewModelWrapper)));
    }
}
```

With this, the XAML is mostly like what you originally had, but with a style applied to the optional `StackPanel` element that has a trigger to show or hide the element according to whether the property is present or not:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSO46736914MissingProperty.UserControl1"
             x:ClassModifier="internal"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO46736914MissingProperty"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding ViewModelWrapper, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation ="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5">
      <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=OnOffAlways}"/>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Always}">
        <TextBlock Text="On/Off"/>
      </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation ="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,5">
      <StackPanel.Style>
        <p:Style TargetType="StackPanel">
          <p:Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasSometimes}" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </p:Style.Triggers>
        </p:Style>
      </StackPanel.Style>
      <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Path=OnOffSometimes}"/>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Sometimes}">
        <TextBlock Text="On/Off"/>
      </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note that the top-level `Grid` element's `DataContext` is set to the `UserControl`'s `ViewModelWrapper` property, so that the contained elements use that object instead of the view model assigned by the parent code.

(You can ignore the `p:` XML namespace…that's there only because Stack Overflow's XAML formatting gets confused by `<Style/>` elements that use the default XML namespace.)

While I in general would prefer the template-based approach, as the idiomatic and inherently simpler one, this wrapper-based approach does have some advantages:

- It can be used in situations where the `UserControl` object is declared in an assembly different from the one where the view model types are declared, and where the latter assembly cannot be referenced by the former.
- It removes the redundancy that is required by the template-based approach. I.e. rather than having to copy/paste the shared elements of the templates, this approach uses a single XAML structure for the entire view, and shows or hides elements of that view as appropriate.

For completeness, here is the `NotifyPropertyChangedBase` class used by the `ViewModelWrapper` class above:

```
class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        _RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void _RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, I prefer this approach to re-implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in each model object. The code is a lot simpler and easier to write, simpler to read, and less prone to errors.

Comment: I like the wrapper solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple solution using DataTriggers and a custom converter:

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={HasPropertyConverter PropertyName=Sometimes}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Sometimes}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The converter:

```
public class HasPropertyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PropertyName))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return value?.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName) != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

public class HasPropertyConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => new HasPropertyConverter { PropertyName = PropertyName };
}
```